# Sharing Variables with Concurrency

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I am trying to a write a Java program that has multiple threads. I have two variables that are created on startup. One is an AtomicBoolean that tells the whole program when to shutdown (i.e close the clients). Another variable is a ConcurrentHashMap that contains a set of commands that are loaded in at startup. There are threads that contain a client runnable that run when a client has been accepted (one thread per client). There is also a thread that updates the commands to the HashMap by listening for external changes (new commands from a directory, etc.)

Here is the code:

```
class Program {
    /* ... other vars like ServerSocket, etc. */
    private final ConcurrentHashMap<String, String> mCommands;
    private final AtomicBoolean mIsListening;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Program prog = new Program();
        prog.loadCommands();
        prog.listen();
    }

    public Program() {
        mCommands = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
        mIsListening = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        /* other initializations */
    }

    public void loadCommands() {
         /* Loads commands generated from a directory; updates mCommands, then... */
         new Thread(new CommandListenerRunnable(mCommands)).start();
    }

    public void listen() {
        /* accepting a new client from server socket */
        while (mIsListening.get()) {
            Socket client = ss.accept();
            new Thread(new ClientRunnable(client, mCommands, mIsListening)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, with every child that I am creating, I am passing these variables as arguments. All in all, is this the proper way to distribute these variables? Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's probably safer to keep control over the fields and just pass a reference to `this`.

Comment: @shmosel care to elaborate in an answer and I'll mark it as correct if it suffices? Trying to understand how to use the reference to this in context with the Runnables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the design is good because each thread should have a copy of the variables it needs.

You said:

> For instance, I can use map.putIfAbsent() to make the operation be performed atomically

but this does not make your map thread safe because someone could call something else on it.

Comment: Thank you for the design input. As for the second part,  i understand what you're saying if we were talking about a regular  HashMap. However, I thought the whole point behind the ConcurrentHashMap was to make it thread safe by allowing reads and writes to it be atomically?

Comment: You can see here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html that ConcurrentHashMap implements Map interface so it gets all map functionality like put and so on.... See the api to understand which and why methods are not atomic.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it's not foolproof. Read all the [caveats](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) in the documentation of ConcurrentHashMap such as--

> "the results of aggregate status methods including size, isEmpty, and
>   containsValue are typically useful only when a map is not undergoing
>   concurrent updates in other threads."

If those limitations are acceptable, then what you have is fine. Otherwise you will need your own locking scheme to govern access.

It could be something as simple as `synchronized(sharedLockingObject)`, or something as complex as a [ReentrantReadWriteLock](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/ReentrantReadWriteLock.html).

Comment: There are a lot of caveats. However, I don't think it's the synchronization part I'll have an issue with. For instance, I can use map.putIfAbsent() to make the operation be performed atomically. I'm just more concerned on whether my design choice of passing these variables in is the proper way.

Comment: @Zack well it does sound like you may be reinventing the Thread interrupt mechanism by passing in your own boolean to serve the same purpose? I don't see any design flaw with it, however.

Comment: This is true. However, it's either you use a global variable to shut them down or have to store a reference of each client to call the interrupt for each child. But thank you so much for all of the input.

Comment: @Zack assuming you use an ExecutorService (which you should), all the threads on that service can be interrupted via `shutdownNow()`

Comment: I am actually not using one. But seems like a good data structure to implement! Shouldn't be too hard to change around and would remove that atomic boolean. :)